# Adding Spreadsheets with open XML SDK

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, openxml-sdk

I'm attempting to alter a pre-existing office document by inserting an externally loaded image using open XML SDK 2.5. I plan to do this in excel by appending a worksheet that to the workbook and then doing all of the work there.  However, I can't seem to get around one error in particular.

My code is:

```
    public void insert(String filepath)
    {
        SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filepath, false);

        // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = doc.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

        // Add Sheets to the Workbook.
        Sheets sheets = doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.
            AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

        // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
        Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
        {
            Id = doc.WorkbookPart.
            GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
            SheetId = 1,
            Name = "mySheet"
        };
        sheets.Append(sheet);

        // Close the document.
        doc.Close();
    }
```

Line 6 (adding a new worksheet part) throws an IO exception each time I try to test the program. Most of this code was taken from the MSDN. The very same site suggested that if I'm getting an IO exception, I may have input the wrong filepath, but that is definitely not the case. I also verified that the members I'm accessing are indeed public, so I'm a bit confused. Can anyone tell me what this error may be? I'm hoping it's something simple. This is my first time using C#.

EDIT: I should mention the exception message also states "cannot open a read only container", but I have verified that the file is NOT read only and excel is  NOT open.

Comment: @Donal No I do not. And I don't see excel in the list of running processes.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `false` to the `isEditable` argument when opening the file.

```
SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filepath, false)
```

This makes the document read-only. If you change it to `true`, it should work better.

More information:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc562356
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee880344

---

I would first read the file content into a `MemoryStream`, and open that instead. This would reduce the risk of file corruption.

```
var memory = new MemoryStream();
using (var file = File.OpenRead(filepath))
{
    file.CopyTo(memory);
}
memory.Position = 0;

var doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(memory, true);

//...

doc.Close();

File.WriteAllBytes(filepath, memory.ToArray());
```

Comment: Oh wow thank you! A circumstance of my inexperience with the tool. Now I just have file corruption to worry about!